# How to prevent navigating out from a page _conditionally_?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a diagram editor in a browser.
I would like to warn the user the potential loss if she/he has unsaved edit in the editor and tries to navigate out.

*However I **do not want** to bother the user with this question if **there are no unsaved changes**.*

I find out I can prevent and ask the user via registering to the onbeforeunload event.

```
$(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "You have unsaved changes...";
    }
});
```

I can not find out what should I do **not to display** this dialog, if **there are no** unsaved changes...

Comment: Do you have some code that checks the editors status to see if its been saved?

Comment: There is not enough information here to help much. You'd have to track the state of whatever is changing, or have a way to know that the user edited whatever it is they're editing.

Comment: Interestingly there are people who completely understood the point... obviously I am not asking how to track my editor state is dirty or not. Even the question title clears this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *not* show the dialog, all you have to do is return a void value from the handler. So you could just wrap the `return` in an `if` statement:

```
$(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if(hasUnsavedChanges()) {
            return "You have unsaved changes...";
        }
    }
});
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload):

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to
>   confirm the page unload

Comment: Thanks. (I was trying to return with false, or true both converted to strings) I am going to accept this after the time lock expires

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a `null` value to not display anything:

```
$(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (anyChanges) {
            return "You have unsaved changes...";
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

On `else` this code will allow to page to be closed silently.